# "TypeError: window is not defined" when not even using the window object in Gatsby build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux, gatsby, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to complete the build process of my gatsby e-commerce website.

Normally, the common error "window is not defined" is easily debugged because the error also outputs the location and the code that's referencing the window object in the server-side rendering. But the only thing being outputted for me is the following:
[image: "window" is not available during server side rendering]

And it gives no indication of where the error is happening.
Furthermore, a search of my entire project and even node_modules for the keyword 'window' doesn't return anything!

I should note that all code is being imported through node_modules. I don't have any imports from CDNs or something else.
What else could be throwing this error if the windows object is not even being declared?

Here are my dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.29",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.13.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.11",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-plugin-graphql-js-client-transform": "^1.1.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "dotenv": "8.2.0",
    "gatsby": "2.23.3",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.4.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-env-variables": "1.0.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-express": "^1.1.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^2.3.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.3.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.6.14",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.3.18",
    "gatsby-source-shopify": "3.2.11",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.5.7",
    "graphql-js-client": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql-js-schema": "^0.7.1",
    "postcss-cli": "^7.1.1",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-nested": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "shopify-buy": "^2.11.0"
  },
```

This is incredibly frustrating. Any insight on something that might be causing this will greatly help me.

Comment: do you use redux web extension ?
loading it in gatsby may cause a problem

Comment: No, all my dependencies are shown above. I use redux toolkit, but I haven't seen anyone else have that problem with it. :'(

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue:
I was using gatsby's `navigate` function before a component was mounted, to redirect the user if they were not authenticated. `Navigate` uses the window object under the hood. It makes sense I wasn't able to find it by searching in my `node_modules` folder since it's installed globally.
I found it by trying to make a minimal reproduction. When I added the pages that had `navigate` the build failed, but this time, it showed me exactly what was causing the error! I still don't know why my real project isn't outputting verbose errors.

I guess the lack of the verbose error outputs is the real issue here, and I haven't been able to recreate it.